# Incomplete HTTP Response from Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

- Tomcat 8.0.17, residing on localhost.

  - Linux Mint 17.1
  - Oracle Java 8.0.1.40-b25

I have a JSP which is very long: It contains a drop-down list with country codes and countries (named in Hebrew). When I try to load 
the JSP from its address, I get in return a partial response. Cutting off at around Portugal (can be anywhere else, depending on the amount of code in the page).

The page address is **example.com/he/index2.jsp**

I think it is related to the size of the page because when I remove some lines, I finally get the response correctly.

I don't get any exceptions or errors, and the response returns with status 200.

I have tried setting the buffer size to 8kb, 32kb, 128kb and 2048kb. When it was 8kb I did get a buffer overflow error, but at 32 and above I didn't get this error and the response was still partial.

I tried to set auto flush to false.

I have tried setting both **maxSwallowSize** and **socketBuffer** to 32768 in **Connector** node in **server.xml**.

Narrowing down the code to minimum, I have an example for the evil page. I have removed all unnecessary Java code, includes, etc. The remarked includes are essential because I do need these CSS files. Just for the inspection I commented them out, but I still get the partial response.

Don't know if it is related, I have a request filter that parses this address, sees that the the address starts with **/he/** and attaches a Session object to the request. The object contains a String as a session ID, A Locale and a String as the referrer. Then it forwards the request to **index2.jsp**.

I would appreciate any help of solving this issue.

The minimum page that causes the problem:
The **last paragraph** element is used to indicate if the response is correct.

```html
<%@ page buffer="2048kb" autoFlush="false" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!--     <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> -->
    <!--     <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> -->
    <!--     <link href="/css/theme-style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> -->
    <!--     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    <!--     <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <!--     <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <select>
        <option value="IL">ישראל</option>
        <option value="UG">אוגנדה</option>
        <option value="AT">אוסטריה</option>
        <option value="AU">אוסטרליה</option>
        <option value="UA">אוקראינה</option>
        <option value="UY">אורוגוואי</option>
        <option value="AZ">אזרבייג'ן</option>
        <option value="AE">איחוד האמירויות הערביות</option>
        <option value="IT">איטליה</option>
        <option value="BS">איי בהאמה</option>
        <option value="VG">איי הבתולה הבריטיים</option>
        <option value="TC">איי טורקס וקאיקוס</option>
        <option value="MH">איי מרשל</option>
        <option value="SJ">איי סבאלברד ויאן מאיין</option>
        <option value="SC">איי סיישל</option>
        <option value="FO">איי פארו</option>
        <option value="FK">איי פוקלנד</option>
        <option value="PN">איי פיטקרן</option>
        <option value="CK">איי קוק</option>
        <option value="KY">איי קיימן</option>
        <option value="SB">איי שלמה</option>
        <option value="ID">אינדונזיה</option>
        <option value="IS">איסלנד</option>
        <option value="IE">אירלנד</option>
        <option value="SV">אל סלוודור</option>
        <option value="AL">אלבניה</option>
        <option value="DZ">אלג'יריה</option>
        <option value="AI">אנגווילה</option>
        <option value="AO">אנגולה</option>
        <option value="AD">אנדורה</option>
        <option value="AG">אנטיגואה וברבודה</option>
        <option value="EE">אסטוניה</option>
        <option value="EC">אקוודור</option>
        <option value="AR">ארגנטינה</option>
        <option value="AW">ארובה</option>
        <option value="ER">אריתריאה</option>
        <option value="AM">ארמניה</option>
        <option value="US">ארצות הברית</option>
        <option value="ET">אתיופיה</option>
        <option value="BT">בהוטן</option>
        <option value="BW">בוטסואנה</option>
        <option value="BG">בולגריה</option>
        <option value="BO">בוליביה</option>
        <option value="BA">בוסניה והרצגובינה</option>
        <option value="BI">בורונדי</option>
        <option value="BF">בורקינה פאסו</option>
        <option value="BH">בחריין</option>
        <option value="BY">בלארוס</option>
        <option value="BE">בלגיה</option>
        <option value="BZ">בליז</option>
        <option value="BJ">בנין</option>
        <option value="BB">ברבדוס</option>
        <option value="BN">ברוניי</option>
        <option value="BR">ברזיל</option>
        <option value="GB">בריטניה</option>
        <option value="BM">ברמודה</option>
        <option value="DJ">ג'יבוטי</option>
        <option value="JM">ג'מייקה</option>
        <option value="GE">גאורגיה</option>
        <option value="GA">גבון</option>
        <option value="GT">גואטמלה</option>
        <option value="GP">גוואדלופ</option>
        <option value="GY">גיאנה</option>
        <option value="GF">גיאנה הצרפתית</option>
        <option value="GI">גיברלטר</option>
        <option value="GN">גינאה</option>
        <option value="GW">גינאה ביסאו</option>
        <option value="GM">גמביה</option>
        <option value="GL">גרינלנד</option>
        <option value="DE">גרמניה</option>
        <option value="GD">גרנדה</option>
        <option value="DM">דומיניקה</option>
        <option value="DK">דנמרק</option>
        <option value="ZA">דרום אפריקה</option>
        <option value="KR">דרום קוריאה</option>
        <option value="NF">האי נורפוק</option>
        <option value="AN">האנטילים ההולנדיים</option>
        <option value="IN">הודו</option>
        <option value="NL">הולנד</option>
        <option value="HK">הונג קונג</option>
        <option value="HU">הונגריה</option>
        <option value="HN">הונדורס</option>
        <option value="PH">הפיליפינים</option>
        <option value="DO">הרפובליקה הדומיניקנית</option>
        <option value="CD">הרפובליקה הדמוקרטית של קונגו</option>
        <option value="WF">ואליס ופוטונה</option>
        <option value="VN">וייטנאם</option>
        <option value="VU">ונואטו</option>
        <option value="VE">ונצואלה</option>
        <option value="ZW">זימבבואה</option>
        <option value="ZM">זמביה</option>
        <option value="CI">חוף השנהב</option>
        <option value="TW">טאיוואן</option>
        <option value="TJ">טג'יקיסטן</option>
        <option value="TV">טובאלו</option>
        <option value="TG">טוגו</option>
        <option value="TO">טונגה</option>
        <option value="TN">טוניסיה</option>
        <option value="TR">טורקיה</option>
        <option value="TM">טורקמניסטן</option>
        <option value="TZ">טנזניה</option>
        <option value="TT">טרינידד וטובגו</option>
        <option value="GR">יוון</option>
        <option value="JP">יפן</option>
        <option value="JO">ירדן</option>
        <option value="KW">כווית</option>
        <option value="LA">לאוס</option>
        <option value="LU">לוקסמבורג</option>
        <option value="LV">לטביה</option>
        <option value="LT">ליטא</option>
        <option value="LI">ליכטנשטיין</option>
        <option value="LS">לסוטו</option>
        <option value="MR">מאוריטניה</option>
        <option value="MU">מאוריציוס</option>
        <option value="YT">מאיוט</option>
        <option value="ML">מאלי</option>
        <option value="MG">מדגסקר</option>
        <option value="VA">מדינת קריית הוותיקן</option>
        <option value="MZ">מוזמביק</option>
        <option value="MD">מולדובה</option>
        <option value="MN">מונגוליה</option>
        <option value="ME">מונטנגרו</option>
        <option value="MS">מונטסראט</option>
        <option value="MC">מונקו</option>
        <option value="FM">מיקרונזיה</option>
        <option value="MW">מלאווי</option>
        <option value="MV">מלדיביים</option>
        <option value="MY">מלזיה</option>
        <option value="MT">מלטה</option>
        <option value="EG">מצרים</option>
        <option value="MK">מקדוניה</option>
        <option value="MX">מקסיקו</option>
        <option value="MA">מרוקו</option>
        <option value="MQ">מרטיניק</option>
        <option value="NR">נאורו</option>
        <option value="NO">נורווגיה</option>
        <option value="NG">ניגריה</option>
        <option value="NZ">ניו זילנד</option>
        <option value="NU">ניואה</option>
        <option value="NE">ניז'ר</option>
        <option value="NI">ניקרגואה</option>
        <option value="NA">נמיביה</option>
        <option value="NP">נפאל</option>
        <option value="ST">סאו תומה ופרינסיפה</option>
        <option value="SZ">סווזילנד</option>
        <option value="SO">סומליה</option>
        <option value="SR">סורינאם</option>
        <option value="SL">סיירה ליאונה</option>
        <option value="C2">סין</option>
        <option value="SG">סינגפור</option>
        <option value="SI">סלובניה</option>
        <option value="SK">סלובקיה</option>
        <option value="WS">סמואה</option>
        <option value="SM">סן מרינו</option>
        <option value="SN">סנגל</option>
        <option value="SH">סנט הלנה</option>
        <option value="VC">סנט וינסנט והגרנדינים</option>
        <option value="LC">סנט לוסיה</option>
        <option value="PM">סנט פייר ומיקלון</option>
        <option value="KN">סנט ריטס ונוויס אנגווילה</option>
        <option value="ES">ספרד</option>
        <option value="RS">סרביה</option>
        <option value="LK">סרי לנקה</option>
        <option value="OM">עומן</option>
        <option value="SA">ערב הסעודית</option>
        <option value="PL">פולין</option>
        <option value="PF">פולינזיה הצרפתית</option>
        <option value="PT">פורטוגל</option>
        <option value="FJ">פיג'י</option>
        <option value="FI">פינלנד</option>
        <option value="PW">פלאו</option>
        <option value="PA">פנמה</option>
        <option value="PG">פפואה גינאה החדשה</option>
        <option value="PY">פרגוואי</option>
        <option value="PE">פרו</option>
        <option value="TD">צ'אד</option>
        <option value="CL">צ'ילה</option>
        <option value="CZ">צ'כיה</option>
        <option value="FR">צרפת</option>
        <option value="CO">קולומביה</option>
        <option value="KM">קומורוס</option>
        <option value="CG">קונגו</option>
        <option value="CR">קוסטה ריקה</option>
        <option value="KZ">קזחסטן</option>
        <option value="QA">קטאר</option>
        <option value="CV">קייפ ורדה</option>
        <option value="KG">קירגיזסטן</option>
        <option value="KI">קיריבטי</option>
        <option value="NC">קלדוניה החדשה</option>
        <option value="KH">קמבודיה</option>
        <option value="CM">קמרון</option>
        <option value="CA">קנדה</option>
        <option value="KE">קניה</option>
        <option value="CY">קפריסין</option>
        <option value="HR">קרואטיה</option>
        <option value="RE">ראוניון</option>
        <option value="RW">רואנדה</option>
        <option value="RO">רומניה</option>
        <option value="RU">רוסיה</option>
        <option value="SE">שוודיה</option>
        <option value="CH">שוויץ</option>
        <option value="TH">תאילנד</option>
        <option value="YE">תימן</option>
    </select>
    <p>Last paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo: The URL is of course example.com/he/index2.jsp

Comment: Why do you use  autoFlush="false" ? Why not leave it at the default value of true?

Comment: The reason for this is to see if I am getting the buffer overflow exception. In both cases I got the same incomplete response,

Comment: Did a quick test of your code on my Fedora 22 (Tomcat 8.0.17, Oracle Java 1.8.0_45-b14) and it seems to work correctly. So I suspect the problem could be in the filter - would you mind to share its code?

Comment: Exactly @JozefChocholacek. You have directed me to the correct place. I have edited the buffer size in the filter instead of the JSP itself, and now everything is working well. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jozef Chocholacek I have figured out the solution.

> Did a quick test of your code on my Fedora 22 (Tomcat 8.0.17, Oracle Java 1.8.0_45-b14) and it seems to work correctly. So I suspect the problem could be in the filter - would you mind to share its code?

Since the response is going through a filter, I should have set the buffer size there using `response.setBufferSize(...)`.
Now everything is working well.

Comment: I still don't understand why it wouldn't work with the default values of autoFlush and buffer.  The buffering mechanism should work with any  page size.  The only problem I can imagine is that your filter could overflow the buffer before the response headers can be sent.

Comment: I am not completely sure myself. The reason for setting the autoflush is to verify that problem indeed came from  a buffer overflow. I also don't completely understand why increasing the buffer in the JSP didn't work and didn't raise an exception, and in the filter it did. Buffer of 8k rose an exception in the JSP but larger buffers didn't. I guess that the configuration in the filter somehow overrode or masked the ones from the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case in Jboss 5 where the page was returned incomplete. There were no errors and no exceptions. After many hours of researching and refactoring all the code involved without finding a solution, I found that a string attribute used on the page had corrupted characters, which caused the response generated to be returned incomplete. Hope this helps someone with the same problem.